# Dynamic dropdown with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have created the dynamic dropdown depend on response using *ngFor

Response

```
  Array(3)
        0:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id:1
        is_optional:false
        is_text:false


        1:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id: 2
        is_optional:false
        is_text:false


        2:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id :3
        is_optional: false
        is_text: false
```

HTML

```
 <div *ngIf="response != null">
   <p class="">Questions</p>

       <div *ngFor="let question of response" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
       <p>{{question?.question_eng}} </p>
       </div>
       <div *ngIf= "question.is_text == false" class="col-md-7">
       <select class="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="questions" (click)="GetOptionQuestion(question)">
          <option *ngFor = "let option of responseoption">{{option?.name}} </option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

from this above code i am able to create three dropdowns with options, but when i click any one of the dropdown and choose option,all other remaining dropdown option also changing with same option value.

please help me to avoid the other dropdown changing.

Comment: can you create  a working stackblitz?

Comment: Can you add the `GetOptionQuestion(question)` method body and the `responseoption` property?

Comment: `GetOptionQuestion(question){
    var data = question.id;
    this.values= data;
    this.questionsService.GetQuestionOption(this.values)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.responseoption = data;
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a `name` or `id` attribute to your dynamic `<select..` tag. That will resolve the issue,

For example,

```
    <div *ngIf= "question.is_text == false" class="col-md-7">
      <select name="select{{option?.name}}" class="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="questions" (click)="GetOptionQuestion(question)">
      <option *ngFor = "let option of responseoption">{{option?.name}} </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David R, still i am facing same probelm. all other dropddown also changing.